# ng-repeat and polymorphic directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm wondering if there is a way to build a custom Element directive to use with ng-repeat in this way:

```
<div class="list">
      <my-custom-directive class="item item-icon-right" ng-repeat="a in concepts">
          <p>{{::a.label}}</p>
          <i class="icon ion-forward muted"></i>
      </my-custom-directive>
</div>
```

`my-custom-directive` should compile itself in an **anchor** if `a.href` exists, in a **paragraph** if it doesn't.

**The problem basically is merely design**: I have some items which doesn't have an href, but they should still be in the list. In Ionic1 it looks like I can do a `div` list or an `a` list, but not mixing up without breaking the list design..

Comment: did you see the `transclude` attribute of directives ?

Comment: would it not be an overkill to create a custom directive for this? can you not have two `ng-show` to check and display accordingly?

Comment: @tanmay it's the element of the iteration itself that should mutate, not some child. I'm in this ackward situation because adding any DOM element between `div.list` and `a.item` or `div.item` breaks the list design in Ionic1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. Something like this:

```
<my-custom-dir ng-repeat="a in concepts"></my-custom-dir>
```

where, directive is like,

```
app.directive('myCustomDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'custom.html'
  }
})
```

And, the `custom.html` template,

```
<p ng-hide="a.href">{{::a.label}}</p>
<a ng-href="{{a.href}}" ng-show="a.href">{{::a.label}}</a>
<i class="icon ion-forward muted"></i>
```

Also, I kept the `$scope.concepts` to have dummy object as follows,

```
$scope.concepts = [{
    href: 'eample.com',
    label: 'example'
  }, {
    label: 'example1'
  }, {
    href: 'eample2.com',
    label: 'example2'
  }]
```

[**working example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EkAO3brKMxjoVm7jlkjU?p=preview)

Although, I think you should be able to have a `div.item` with `ng-repeat` inside your `.list`. And in the `div.item` you should be able to have whatever you want (not sure how ionic1 deals with that though)

Comment: Yeah thanks. I indeed I think Ionic could deals with that I will dig into more